# Barcode Scanner (Zxing) integration issue

Tags: android, zxing, barcode-scanner

I am trying to integrate the barcode scanner into my application for Android devices.

I was working good unless i updated my ADT to 1.7 and now I have started over and cant get past this issue, there arent any errors in code

Please Help

```
03-27 21:30:13.440: E/AndroidRuntime(15823): FATAL EXCEPTION: main
03-27 21:30:13.440: E/AndroidRuntime(15823): java.lang.RuntimeException: Unable to start activity ComponentInfo{com.rhuf.brandscan/com.google.zxing.client.android.CaptureActivity}: java.lang.ClassCastException: android.widget.TextView
03-27 21:30:13.440: E/AndroidRuntime(15823):    at android.app.ActivityThread.performLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:1872)
03-27 21:30:13.440: E/AndroidRuntime(15823):    at android.app.ActivityThread.handleLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:1893)
03-27 21:30:13.440: E/AndroidRuntime(15823):    at android.app.ActivityThread.access$1500(ActivityThread.java:135)
03-27 21:30:13.440: E/AndroidRuntime(15823):    at android.app.ActivityThread$H.handleMessage(ActivityThread.java:1054)
03-27 21:30:13.440: E/AndroidRuntime(15823):    at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:99)
03-27 21:30:13.440: E/AndroidRuntime(15823):    at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:150)
03-27 21:30:13.440: E/AndroidRuntime(15823):    at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:4385)
03-27 21:30:13.440: E/AndroidRuntime(15823):    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invokeNative(Native Method)
03-27 21:30:13.440: E/AndroidRuntime(15823):    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:507)
03-27 21:30:13.440: E/AndroidRuntime(15823):    at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:849)
03-27 21:30:13.440: E/AndroidRuntime(15823):    at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:607)
03-27 21:30:13.440: E/AndroidRuntime(15823):    at dalvik.system.NativeStart.main(Native Method)
03-27 21:30:13.440: E/AndroidRuntime(15823): Caused by: java.lang.ClassCastException: android.widget.TextView
03-27 21:30:13.440: E/AndroidRuntime(15823):    at com.google.zxing.client.android.CaptureActivity.onCreate(CaptureActivity.java:141)
03-27 21:30:13.440: E/AndroidRuntime(15823):    at android.app.Instrumentation.callActivityOnCreate(Instrumentation.java:1072)
03-27 21:30:13.440: E/AndroidRuntime(15823):    at android.app.ActivityThread.performLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:1836)
    public final class CaptureActivity extends Activity implements SurfaceHolder.Callback {
  private static final String TAG = "CaptureActivity";    
  private static final int SHARE_ID = Menu.FIRST;
  private static final int HISTORY_ID = Menu.FIRST + 1;
  private static final int SETTINGS_ID = Menu.FIRST + 2;
  private static final int HELP_ID = Menu.FIRST + 3;
  private static final int ABOUT_ID = Menu.FIRST + 4;

  private static final int MAX_RESULT_IMAGE_SIZE = 150;
  private static final long INTENT_RESULT_DURATION = 1500L;
  private static final float BEEP_VOLUME = 0.10f;
  private static final long VIBRATE_DURATION = 200L;

  private static final String PACKAGE_NAME = "com.google.zxing.client.android";
  private static final String PRODUCT_SEARCH_URL_PREFIX = "http://www.google";
  private static final String PRODUCT_SEARCH_URL_SUFFIX = "/m/products/scan";
  private static final String ZXING_URL = "http://zxing.appspot.com/scan";

  private enum Source {
    NATIVE_APP_INTENT,
    PRODUCT_SEARCH_LINK,
    ZXING_LINK,
    NONE
  }

  private CaptureActivityHandler handler;
  private ViewfinderView viewfinderView;
  private View statusView;
  private View resultView;
  private MediaPlayer mediaPlayer;
  private Result lastResult;
  private boolean hasSurface;
  private boolean playBeep;
  private boolean vibrate;
  private boolean copyToClipboard;
  private Source source;
  private String sourceUrl;
  private String decodeMode;
  private String versionName;
  private HistoryManager historyManager;

  private final OnCompletionListener beepListener = new BeepListener(); 
  private final DialogInterface.OnClickListener aboutListener =
      new DialogInterface.OnClickListener() {
    public void onClick(DialogInterface dialogInterface, int i) {
      Intent intent = new Intent(Intent.ACTION_VIEW, Uri.parse(getString(R.string.zxing_url)));
      startActivity(intent);
    }
  };

  public Handler getHandler() {
    return handler;
  }

  @Override
  public void onCreate(Bundle icicle) {
    super.onCreate(icicle);

    Window window = getWindow();
    window.addFlags(WindowManager.LayoutParams.FLAG_KEEP_SCREEN_ON);
    setContentView(R.layout.capture);

    CameraManager.init(getApplication());
    viewfinderView = (ViewfinderView) findViewById(R.id.viewfinder_view);
    resultView = findViewById(R.id.result_view);
    statusView = findViewById(R.id.status_view);
    handler = null;
    lastResult = null;
    hasSurface = false;
    historyManager = new HistoryManager(this);
    historyManager.trimHistory();

    showHelpOnFirstLaunch();
  }

  @Override
  protected void onResume() {
    super.onResume();

    SurfaceView surfaceView = (SurfaceView) findViewById(R.id.preview_view);
    SurfaceHolder surfaceHolder = surfaceView.getHolder();
    if (hasSurface) {
      // The activity was paused but not stopped, so the surface still exists. Therefore
      // surfaceCreated() won't be called, so init the camera here.
      initCamera(surfaceHolder);
    } else {
      // Install the callback and wait for surfaceCreated() to init the camera.
      surfaceHolder.addCallback(this);
      surfaceHolder.setType(SurfaceHolder.SURFACE_TYPE_PUSH_BUFFERS);
    }

    Intent intent = getIntent();
    String action = intent == null ? null : intent.getAction();
    String dataString = intent == null ? null : intent.getDataString();
    if (intent != null && action != null) {
      if (action.equals(Intents.Scan.ACTION)) {
        // Scan the formats the intent requested, and return the result to the calling activity.
        source = Source.NATIVE_APP_INTENT;
        decodeMode = intent.getStringExtra(Intents.Scan.MODE);
        resetStatusView();
      } else if (dataString != null && dataString.contains(PRODUCT_SEARCH_URL_PREFIX) &&
          dataString.contains(PRODUCT_SEARCH_URL_SUFFIX)) {
        // Scan only products and send the result to mobile Product Search.
        source = Source.PRODUCT_SEARCH_LINK;
        sourceUrl = dataString;
        decodeMode = Intents.Scan.PRODUCT_MODE;
        resetStatusView();
      } else if (dataString != null && dataString.equals(ZXING_URL)) {
        // Scan all formats and handle the results ourselves.
        // TODO: In the future we could allow the hyperlink to include a URL to send the results to.
        source = Source.ZXING_LINK;
        sourceUrl = dataString;
        decodeMode = null;
        resetStatusView();
      } else {
        // Scan all formats and handle the results ourselves (launched from Home).
        source = Source.NONE;
        decodeMode = null;
        resetStatusView();
      }
    } else {
      source = Source.NONE;
      decodeMode = null;
      if (lastResult == null) {
        resetStatusView();
      }
    }

    SharedPreferences prefs = PreferenceManager.getDefaultSharedPreferences(this);
    playBeep = prefs.getBoolean(PreferencesActivity.KEY_PLAY_BEEP, true);
    vibrate = prefs.getBoolean(PreferencesActivity.KEY_VIBRATE, false);
    copyToClipboard = prefs.getBoolean(PreferencesActivity.KEY_COPY_TO_CLIPBOARD, true);
    initBeepSound();
  }

  @Override
  protected void onPause() {
    super.onPause();
    if (handler != null) {
      handler.quitSynchronously();
      handler = null;
    }
    CameraManager.get().closeDriver();
  }

  @Override
  public boolean onKeyDown(int keyCode, KeyEvent event) {
    if (keyCode == KeyEvent.KEYCODE_BACK) {
      if (source == Source.NATIVE_APP_INTENT) {
        setResult(RESULT_CANCELED);
        finish();
        return true;
      } else if ((source == Source.NONE || source == Source.ZXING_LINK) && lastResult != null) {
        resetStatusView();
        handler.sendEmptyMessage(R.id.restart_preview);
        return true;
      }
    } else if (keyCode == KeyEvent.KEYCODE_FOCUS || keyCode == KeyEvent.KEYCODE_CAMERA) {
      // Handle these events so they don't launch the Camera app
      return true;
    }
    return super.onKeyDown(keyCode, event);
  }

  @Override
  public boolean onCreateOptionsMenu(Menu menu) {
    super.onCreateOptionsMenu(menu);
    menu.add(0, SHARE_ID, 0, R.string.menu_share).setIcon(R.drawable.share_menu_item);
    menu.add(0, HISTORY_ID, 0, R.string.menu_history)
        .setIcon(android.R.drawable.ic_menu_recent_history);
    menu.add(0, SETTINGS_ID, 0, R.string.menu_settings)
        .setIcon(android.R.drawable.ic_menu_preferences);
    menu.add(0, HELP_ID, 0, R.string.menu_help)
        .setIcon(android.R.drawable.ic_menu_help);
    menu.add(0, ABOUT_ID, 0, R.string.menu_about)
        .setIcon(android.R.drawable.ic_menu_info_details);
    return true;
  }

  // Don't display the share menu item if the result overlay is showing.
  @Override
  public boolean onPrepareOptionsMenu(Menu menu) {
    super.onPrepareOptionsMenu(menu);
    menu.findItem(SHARE_ID).setVisible(lastResult == null);
    return true;
  }

  @Override
  public boolean onOptionsItemSelected(MenuItem item) {
    switch (item.getItemId()) {
      case SHARE_ID: {
        Intent intent = new Intent(Intent.ACTION_VIEW);
        intent.setClassName(this, ShareActivity.class.getName());
        startActivity(intent);
        break;
      }
      case HISTORY_ID: {
        AlertDialog historyAlert = historyManager.buildAlert();
        historyAlert.show();
        break;
      }
      case SETTINGS_ID: {
        Intent intent = new Intent(Intent.ACTION_VIEW);
        intent.setClassName(this, PreferencesActivity.class.getName());
        startActivity(intent);
        break;
      }
      case HELP_ID: {
        Intent intent = new Intent(Intent.ACTION_VIEW);
        intent.setClassName(this, HelpActivity.class.getName());
        startActivity(intent);
        break;
      }
      case ABOUT_ID:
        AlertDialog.Builder builder = new AlertDialog.Builder(this);
        builder.setTitle(getString(R.string.title_about) + versionName);
        builder.setMessage(getString(R.string.msg_about) + "\n\n" + getString(R.string.zxing_url));
        builder.setIcon(R.drawable.zxing_icon);
        builder.setPositiveButton(R.string.button_open_browser, aboutListener);
        builder.setNegativeButton(R.string.button_cancel, null);
        builder.show();
        break;
    }
    return super.onOptionsItemSelected(item);
  }

  @Override
  public void onConfigurationChanged(Configuration config) {
    // Do nothing, this is to prevent the activity from being restarted when the keyboard opens.
    super.onConfigurationChanged(config);
  }

  public void surfaceCreated(SurfaceHolder holder) {
    if (!hasSurface) {
      hasSurface = true;
      initCamera(holder);
    }
  }
  public void surfaceDestroyed(SurfaceHolder holder) {
    hasSurface = false;
  }

  public void surfaceChanged(SurfaceHolder holder, int format, int width, int height) {

  }

  /**
   * A valid barcode has been found, so give an indication of success and show the results.
   *
   * @param rawResult The contents of the barcode.
   * @param barcode   A greyscale bitmap of the camera data which was decoded.
   */
  public void handleDecode(Result rawResult, Bitmap barcode) {
    lastResult = rawResult;
    historyManager.addHistoryItem(rawResult);
    if (barcode == null) {
      // This is from history -- no saved barcode
      handleDecodeInternally(rawResult, null);
    } else {
      playBeepSoundAndVibrate();
      drawResultPoints(barcode, rawResult);
      switch (source) {
        case NATIVE_APP_INTENT:
        case PRODUCT_SEARCH_LINK:
          handleDecodeExternally(rawResult, barcode);
          break;
        case ZXING_LINK:
        case NONE:
          handleDecodeInternally(rawResult, barcode);
          break;
      }
    }
  }

  /**
   * Superimpose a line for 1D or dots for 2D to highlight the key features of the barcode.
   *
   * @param barcode   A bitmap of the captured image.
   * @param rawResult The decoded results which contains the points to draw.
   */
  private void drawResultPoints(Bitmap barcode, Result rawResult) {
    ResultPoint[] points = rawResult.getResultPoints();
    if (points != null && points.length > 0) {
      Canvas canvas = new Canvas(barcode);
      Paint paint = new Paint();
      paint.setColor(getResources().getColor(R.color.result_image_border));
      paint.setStrokeWidth(3.0f);
      paint.setStyle(Paint.Style.STROKE);
      Rect border = new Rect(2, 2, barcode.getWidth() - 2, barcode.getHeight() - 2);
      canvas.drawRect(border, paint);

      paint.setColor(getResources().getColor(R.color.result_points));
      if (points.length == 2) {
        paint.setStrokeWidth(4.0f);
        canvas.drawLine(points[0].getX(), points[0].getY(), points[1].getX(),
            points[1].getY(), paint);
      } else {
        paint.setStrokeWidth(10.0f);
        for (ResultPoint point : points) {
          canvas.drawPoint(point.getX(), point.getY(), paint);
        }
      }
    }
  }
  // Put up our own UI for how to handle the decoded contents.
  private void handleDecodeInternally(Result rawResult, Bitmap barcode) {
    statusView.setVisibility(View.GONE);
    viewfinderView.setVisibility(View.GONE);
    resultView.setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);

    if (barcode == null) {
      barcode = ((BitmapDrawable) getResources().getDrawable(R.drawable.unknown_barcode)).getBitmap();
    }
    ImageView barcodeImageView = (ImageView) findViewById(R.id.barcode_image_view);
    barcodeImageView.setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);
    barcodeImageView.setMaxWidth(MAX_RESULT_IMAGE_SIZE);
    barcodeImageView.setMaxHeight(MAX_RESULT_IMAGE_SIZE);
    barcodeImageView.setImageBitmap(barcode);

    TextView formatTextView = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.format_text_view);
    formatTextView.setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);
    formatTextView.setText(getString(R.string.msg_default_format) + ": " +
        rawResult.getBarcodeFormat().toString());

    ResultHandler resultHandler = ResultHandlerFactory.makeResultHandler(this, rawResult);
    TextView typeTextView = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.type_text_view);
    typeTextView.setText(getString(R.string.msg_default_type) + ": " +
        resultHandler.getType().toString());

    TextView contentsTextView = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.contents_text_view);
    CharSequence title = getString(resultHandler.getDisplayTitle());
    SpannableStringBuilder styled = new SpannableStringBuilder(title + "\n\n");
    styled.setSpan(new UnderlineSpan(), 0, title.length(), 0);
    CharSequence displayContents = resultHandler.getDisplayContents();
    styled.append(displayContents);
    contentsTextView.setText(styled);

    int buttonCount = resultHandler.getButtonCount();
    ViewGroup buttonView = (ViewGroup) findViewById(R.id.result_button_view);
    buttonView.requestFocus();
    for (int x = 0; x < ResultHandler.MAX_BUTTON_COUNT; x++) {
      TextView button = (TextView) buttonView.getChildAt(x);
      if (x < buttonCount) {
        button.setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);
        button.setText(resultHandler.getButtonText(x));
        button.setOnClickListener(new ResultButtonListener(resultHandler, x));
      } else {
        button.setVisibility(View.GONE);
      }
    }

    if (copyToClipboard) {
      ClipboardManager clipboard = (ClipboardManager) getSystemService(CLIPBOARD_SERVICE);
      clipboard.setText(displayContents);
    }
  }

  // Briefly show the contents of the barcode, then handle the result outside Barcode Scanner.
  private void handleDecodeExternally(Result rawResult, Bitmap barcode) {
    viewfinderView.drawResultBitmap(barcode);

    // Since this message will only be shown for a second, just tell the user what kind of
    // barcode was found (e.g. contact info) rather than the full contents, which they won't
    // have time to read.
    ResultHandler resultHandler = ResultHandlerFactory.makeResultHandler(this, rawResult);
    TextView textView = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.status_text_view);
    textView.setGravity(Gravity.CENTER);
    textView.setTextSize(18.0f);
    textView.setText(getString(resultHandler.getDisplayTitle()));

    statusView.setBackgroundColor(getResources().getColor(R.color.transparent));

    if (copyToClipboard) {
      ClipboardManager clipboard = (ClipboardManager) getSystemService(CLIPBOARD_SERVICE);
      clipboard.setText(resultHandler.getDisplayContents());
    }

    if (source == Source.NATIVE_APP_INTENT) {
      // Hand back whatever action they requested - this can be changed to Intents.Scan.ACTION when
      // the deprecated intent is retired.
      Intent intent = new Intent(getIntent().getAction());
      intent.putExtra(Intents.Scan.RESULT, rawResult.toString());
      intent.putExtra(Intents.Scan.RESULT_FORMAT, rawResult.getBarcodeFormat().toString());
      Message message = Message.obtain(handler, R.id.return_scan_result);
      message.obj = intent;
      handler.sendMessageDelayed(message, INTENT_RESULT_DURATION);
    } else if (source == Source.PRODUCT_SEARCH_LINK) {
      // Reformulate the URL which triggered us into a query, so that the request goes to the same
      // TLD as the scan URL.
      Message message = Message.obtain(handler, R.id.launch_product_query);
      int end = sourceUrl.lastIndexOf("/scan");
      message.obj = sourceUrl.substring(0, end) + "?q=" +
          resultHandler.getDisplayContents().toString() + "&source=zxing";
      handler.sendMessageDelayed(message, INTENT_RESULT_DURATION);
    }
  }

  /**
   * We want the help screen to be shown automatically the first time a new version of the app is
   * run. The easiest way to do this is to check android:versionCode from the manifest, and compare
   * it to a value stored as a preference.
   */
  private boolean showHelpOnFirstLaunch() {
    try {
      PackageInfo info = getPackageManager().getPackageInfo(PACKAGE_NAME, 0);
      int currentVersion = info.versionCode;
      // Since we're paying to talk to the PackageManager anyway, it makes sense to cache the app
      // version name here for display in the about box later.
      this.versionName = info.versionName;
      SharedPreferences prefs = PreferenceManager.getDefaultSharedPreferences(this);
      int lastVersion = prefs.getInt(PreferencesActivity.KEY_HELP_VERSION_SHOWN, 0);
      if (currentVersion > lastVersion) {
        prefs.edit().putInt(PreferencesActivity.KEY_HELP_VERSION_SHOWN, currentVersion).commit();
        Intent intent = new Intent(Intent.ACTION_VIEW);
        intent.setClassName(this, HelpActivity.class.getName());
        startActivity(intent);
        return true;
      }
    } catch (PackageManager.NameNotFoundException e) {
      Log.w(TAG, e);
    }
    return false;
  }

  /**
   * Creates the beep MediaPlayer in advance so that the sound can be triggered with the least
   * latency possible.
   */
  private void initBeepSound() {
    if (playBeep && mediaPlayer == null) {
      // The volume on STREAM_SYSTEM is not adjustable, and users found it too loud,
      // so we now play on the music stream.
      setVolumeControlStream(AudioManager.STREAM_MUSIC);
      mediaPlayer = new MediaPlayer();
      mediaPlayer.setAudioStreamType(AudioManager.STREAM_MUSIC);
      mediaPlayer.setOnCompletionListener(beepListener);

      AssetFileDescriptor file = getResources().openRawResourceFd(R.raw.beep);
      try {
        mediaPlayer.setDataSource(file.getFileDescriptor(), file.getStartOffset(),
            file.getLength());
        file.close();
        mediaPlayer.setVolume(BEEP_VOLUME, BEEP_VOLUME);
        mediaPlayer.prepare();
      } catch (IOException e) {
        mediaPlayer = null;
      }
    }
  }

  private void playBeepSoundAndVibrate() {
    if (playBeep && mediaPlayer != null) {
      mediaPlayer.start();
    }
    if (vibrate) {
      Vibrator vibrator = (Vibrator) getSystemService(VIBRATOR_SERVICE);
      vibrator.vibrate(VIBRATE_DURATION);
    }
  }
  private void initCamera(SurfaceHolder surfaceHolder) {
    try {
      CameraManager.get().openDriver(surfaceHolder);
    } catch (IOException ioe) {
      Log.w(TAG, ioe);
      return;
    }
    if (handler == null) {
      boolean beginScanning = lastResult == null;
      handler = new CaptureActivityHandler(this, decodeMode, beginScanning);
    }
  }

  private void resetStatusView() {
    resultView.setVisibility(View.GONE);
    statusView.setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);
    statusView.setBackgroundColor(getResources().getColor(R.color.status_view));
    viewfinderView.setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);

    TextView textView = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.status_text_view);
    textView.setGravity(Gravity.LEFT | Gravity.CENTER_VERTICAL);
    textView.setTextSize(14.0f);
    textView.setText(R.string.msg_default_status);
    lastResult = null;
  }

  public void drawViewfinder() {
    viewfinderView.drawViewfinder();
  }

  /**
   * When the beep has finished playing, rewind to queue up another one.
   */
  private static class BeepListener implements OnCompletionListener {
    public void onCompletion(MediaPlayer mediaPlayer) {
      mediaPlayer.seekTo(0);
    }
  }
}
```

**Edit: capture.xml**

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>

<FrameLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
             android:layout_width="fill_parent"
             android:layout_height="fill_parent">

  <SurfaceView android:id="@+id/preview_view"
               android:layout_width="fill_parent"
               android:layout_height="fill_parent"
               android:layout_centerInParent="true"/>

  <com.google.zxing.client.android.ViewfinderView
      android:id="@+id/viewfinder_view"
      android:layout_width="fill_parent"
      android:layout_height="fill_parent"
      android:background="@color/transparent"/>

  <LinearLayout android:id="@+id/result_view"
                android:orientation="vertical"
                android:layout_width="fill_parent"
                android:layout_height="fill_parent"
                android:background="@color/result_view"
                android:visibility="gone"
                android:padding="4dip">

    <LinearLayout
        android:orientation="horizontal"
        android:layout_width="fill_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_weight="1"
        android:gravity="top"
        android:padding="12dip">

      <LinearLayout
          android:orientation="vertical"
          android:layout_width="wrap_content"
          android:layout_height="wrap_content"
          android:gravity="left|top">

        <ImageView android:id="@+id/barcode_image_view"
                   android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                   android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                   android:layout_marginBottom="4dip"
                   android:adjustViewBounds="true"
                   android:scaleType="centerInside"/>

        <TextView android:id="@+id/format_text_view"
                  android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                  android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                  android:layout_gravity="left"
                  android:text="@string/msg_default_format"
                  android:textColor="@color/result_minor_text"
                  android:textSize="14sp"/>

        <TextView android:id="@+id/type_text_view"
                  android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                  android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                  android:layout_gravity="left"
                  android:text="@string/msg_default_type"
                  android:textColor="@color/result_minor_text"
                  android:textSize="14sp"/>

      </LinearLayout>

      <ScrollView
          android:layout_width="fill_parent"
          android:layout_height="wrap_content"
          android:layout_weight="1">

        <TextView android:id="@+id/contents_text_view"
                  android:layout_width="fill_parent"
                  android:layout_height="fill_parent"
                  android:gravity="left|top"
                  android:text="@string/msg_default_contents"
                  android:textColor="@color/result_text"
                  android:textSize="22sp"
                  android:paddingLeft="12dip"
                  android:autoLink="web"/>

      </ScrollView>

    </LinearLayout>

    <LinearLayout android:id="@+id/result_button_view"
                  android:orientation="horizontal"
                  android:layout_width="fill_parent"
                  android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                  android:gravity="center">

      <Button android:layout_width="wrap_content"
              android:layout_height="wrap_content"
              android:visibility="gone"/>

      <Button android:layout_width="wrap_content"
              android:layout_height="wrap_content"
              android:visibility="gone"/>

      <Button android:layout_width="wrap_content"
              android:layout_height="wrap_content"
              android:visibility="gone"/>

      <Button android:layout_width="wrap_content"
              android:layout_height="wrap_content"
              android:visibility="gone"/>

    </LinearLayout>

  </LinearLayout>

  <LinearLayout
      android:orientation="vertical"
      android:layout_width="fill_parent"
      android:layout_height="fill_parent"
      android:background="@color/transparent">

    <FrameLayout
        android:layout_width="fill_parent"
        android:layout_height="fill_parent"
        android:layout_weight="1"
        android:background="@color/transparent"/>

    <LinearLayout android:id="@+id/status_view"
                  android:orientation="horizontal"
                  android:layout_width="fill_parent"
                  android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                  android:layout_weight="0"
                  android:background="@color/status_view"
                  android:baselineAligned="false"
                  android:padding="4dip">

      <TextView android:id="@+id/status_text_view"
                android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:layout_gravity="left|center_vertical"
                android:layout_weight="1"
                android:text="@string/msg_default_status"
                android:textColor="@color/status_text"
                android.textSize="14sp"/>   
    </LinearLayout>    
  </LinearLayout>
</FrameLayout>
```

Comment: Please do *not* copy and paste our UI this much. I'm the author and I strongly discourage such complete cloning.

Comment: is there a better way to use your barcode scanner in our application then let me know. My application just uses the scanner from your SDK to get the result.. anyway i am unable to run it though, going through this issue

Answer (score 2):

`CaptureActivity.java:141` see line `141` have `ClassCastExeption` it means your class doesn't same as defined in `xml` layout file

see this link

https://stackoverflow.com/a/7183137

Comment: how can this be so? I am running the released code by Zxing and integrating it via Intents

Comment: you have this `CaptureActivity.java` file post it?>

Comment: a little too big but I have posted it. It is a part of the zxing project

Comment: it points to this line often

viewfinderView = (ViewfinderView) findViewById(R.id.viewfinder_view);

Comment: please give more information about the way you solved it. i had same problem and i cant solve.